# Lazy loading content web app in amazon EC2

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-ec2, azure-web-app-service, lazy-loading

I'll give a context of what happened to understand better. I used Azure services app to keep my application running, but I created a new datacenter on amazon and migrated my web app to the new server.

I use the iis in it to store the application. It's in asp.net and first there was a slow issue with me.  bundles, but with this new migration I saw that was too slow to load them, in azure app services took about 200ms, already on the new server was for 3 seconds each bundle on screen, I solved this problem just pointed the way of scripts without using bundle.

The way I did it was a palliative solution and I didn't solve the root of the problem, the loading time on the screens is still a bit time consuming and is spoiling the user experience.

In azure the same application in their service app does not take so long, already on the server running on iis is taking too long and I think it is some configuration but I was not successful.

This is the application in azure:
[azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1gVB.png)

This is the application in amazon:
[amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyNG6.png)

This both examples is the same app, same database and same user account. I believe the problem is not in the application but in the server config.

Someone can help me about that?

Comment: did you face this is when open site first time or every time when you load the site? because when the first time loads the site it will take some time to load all the content.

Comment: I've already put the config AlwaysRunning and somethings related about that, even the site is loaded, the website still take too long to load page.
I saw that he is taking too long reading scripts and I don't know why.
For example: in azure the script jquery is readed in page in 200ms, the same script in the same page on amazon data center is readed in 2.3 seconds.

Comment: which region both the server amazon and azure and try to run tracert again both server. The tracert command is a Command Prompt command that's used to show several details about the path that a packet takes from the computer or device you're on to whatever destination you specify.